# Show that every square n is congruent to $ 0$ or $1 \pmod{8}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is odd then $n$ is congruent to $1 \pmod{8}$, but if $n$ is even the we have to do it by cases.

Let $n=2k$

so $n^2=4k^2$.

When $k$ is even, then it's congruent to $0 \pmod{8}$, but when $k$ is odd, I don't see how it would be congruent to something in the options.

Comment: When $n$ is odd, then let $n=2m+1$. Then, $n^2=4m^2+4m+1=4m(m+1)+1$. One of $m$ and $m+1$ has to be divisible by $2$, so $4m(m+1)$ has to be divisible by $8$.

Comment: what about when n is even.

Comment: Then $n$ may be congruent to $0$ or $4$ mod $8$. ($2^2=4\equiv4\mbox{ (mod 8)}$)

Comment: that's what bothers me. It's not in the options. It says it's either $1$ or $0$ mod8$

Comment: Then it's wrong.

Comment: You would have to eliminate those numbers $n= 4k + 2$ for then $n^2 = 16k^2 + 16k + 4$. For the remaining even integers, that is $n = 4k$, the result clearly holds since $n^2 = 16k^2$.

Comment: Another nice way to see the odd case is that every odd number is $4m\pm 1$, and $(4m \pm 1)^2 = 16m^2 \pm 8m + 1$.

Comment: @KennyLau compared to most of the other answers that's very clever, I think you should make that an anwser.

Answer (score 5):

we have $$n\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \mod 8$$ squaring we get $$n^2\equiv 0,1,4,1,0,1,4,1,\mod 8$$

Comment: yes you have right $$36\equiv 4 \mod 8$$ sorry it was a typo

Comment: thank you for the grammar lesson

Comment: you are right! is the exact form

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Every integer has form $\, n = 4q+r\,\ $ for $\,\ r \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}\,$ by the Division Algorithm.

Thus computing modulo $\,8\!:\  n^2\! = (4q+r)^2 \equiv r^2\!\in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}^2  \equiv \{0, 1, 4, 1\}$

Comment: You can simplify by rewriting $\,3\equiv -1\pmod 4\,$ then $\,(\pm1)^2\equiv 1,\,$  i.e. odd$^2\equiv 1\pmod 8\ \ $